# angular cli less cross browser support

Tags: css, angular, less, angular-cli

I'm missing something very simple and could use your help.
I have created a new angular project using angular-cli.
I ran the command `ng new my-app` and chose the option to work with less.

Now when I am running the command `npm run ng serve` my less files are transformed into css files, but i have no cross broswer support, for example i want this:

```css
.my-class{
  display: flex;
}
```

To be translated into this:

```css
.my-class{
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
```

I have searched for some time and couldn't find any thing, im probably missing something simple.

Thanks in advance,
Gabi.

Comment: When in doubt, start at [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-browser-compatibility) :)

Comment: Hey thanks for your respons. I forgot to mention that i tried that, i added browserlist at the end of my package.json, and it still doesnt work for some reason

Comment: Nah it's already baked in. Go to `src folder > browserslist` and view the file. Add the [exception criteria](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) as necessary and you'll probably want to also uncomment the `IE 9-11` rule in there by default like the comments in that file point you to. May take tweaking to get exactly what you want.

Comment: Oh thanks alot! Works great now!